# Choice and count validation help on java guessing game

Tags: java, string, validation, loops, methods

I have seen a lot of this question on here, but the content is either too simple or more complex than what I am trying to do.

My specific issues are understanding how to get the program to start over the number of tries when a new game begins as it will continue to count where it left off, as well as validating the **Yes** or **No** choice `String`. We need to have our validation in separate methods. I've tried so many techniques but I can't get anything to validate and having a learning disability doesn't help...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.lang.Math; 

public class Gamerandom {  
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Guess the Number Game ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100.");
        System.out.println("Try to guess it.");
        System.out.println();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int secretValue;
        secretValue = (int) (Math.random() * 99 + 1);
        int guess; 
        int tries = 0;
        String choice;
        boolean playing = true;

        while(playing) {  

        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        guess = sc.nextInt();
        tries++;

        if (guess == secretValue) {
            if (tries <= 3) {
                System.out.println("You got it in " + tries + " tries.");
                System.out.println("Great Work! You are a mathematical wizard!");
            } else if (tries > 3 && tries <= 7) {
                System.out.println("You got it in " + tries + " tries.");
                System.out.println("Not too bad! You've got some potential. ");
            } else  {
                System.out.println("You got it in " + tries + " tries.");
                System.out.println("What took you so long? Maybe you should take some lessons.");
            }
         } else if (guess < secretValue) {
            System.out.println("Too low! Guess again. \n");
            continue;
        } else if (guess == secretValue +10) {
            System.out.println("Way too high! Guess again. \n");
            continue;
        } else if (guess > secretValue) {
            System.out.print("Too high! Guess again. ");
            continue;
        } 

        System.out.println("Try again? y/n");
        choice = sc.next();      
        }                   
    }  

    public static boolean getChoice(Scanner sc) {
        String choice = "y";
        boolean getChoice = true;

        while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            System.out.println("Error! Entry must be 'y' or 'n'. Try again");
            System.out.println("Try again? (y/n)");
            choice = sc.nextLine();
        }

        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            System.out.println("Bye - Come back again soon!");
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100.");
            System.out.println("Try to guess it. ");

        }
        return false;
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Change this:

   else if (guess == secretValue +10){
       System.out.println("Way too high! Guess again. \n");
       continue;

   }

To this:

```
 else if (guess >= secretValue +10){
        System.out.println("Way too high! Guess again. \n");
        continue;

    }
```

You're almost there with your Y/N...just a few tweaks need to be made.

2. Change this:

   System.out.println("Try again? y/n");
       choice = sc.next();
       }

To this:

```
System.out.println("Try again? y/n");
        choice = sc.next();

        // This will set the boolean to continue the loop
        // or finish the program
        if (playing = getChoice(choice)){
            tries = 0;
        }
```

And finally you need to change your getChoice() method.

3. Change this:

   public static boolean getChoice(Scanner sc) {
       String choice = "y";
       boolean getChoice = true;

   ```
   while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
       System.out.println("Error! Entry must be 'y' or 'n'. Try again");
       System.out.println("Try again? (y/n)");
       choice = sc.nextLine();
   }

   if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
       System.out.println("Bye - Come back again soon!");
       return true;
   } else {
       System.out.println("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100.");
       System.out.println("Try to guess it. ");

   }
   return false;
   }
   ```

To this:

```
// Pass choice in as the parameter instead of a Scanner object
public static boolean getChoice(String choice) {

    // Create a new scanner object
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
        System.out.println("Error! Entry must be 'y' or 'n'. Try again");
        System.out.println("Try again? (y/n)");
        choice = sc.nextLine();
    }
    if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
        System.out.println("Bye - Come back again soon!");
        // This will close your loop and the program will end
        return false;
    } else {
        System.out.println("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100.");
        System.out.println("Try to guess it. ");
        // This will cause your loop to continue
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now you just need to add some exception handling and you should be in business. Best of luck!

Comment: Great! Anything for the Yes or No validation method aswell?

Comment: This is very helpful :). There's another issue that I didn't notice til now though..the try count won't start over when a new game begins. I don't wanna pressure any one person for more advice lol so I'll see where it takes me